# The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, selenium, appium-ios

I have installed Appium 1.6.4 on Mac using Terminal. Also I can able to inspect iPhone WebElements using Safari Browser in MAC.

But I need to inspect the keyboard elements and date picker elements on iPhone real device. For this, I have again installed Appium-desktop 1.0.2 beta2 version. When I launch the Appium desktop(GUI) and run the selenium code. It throws the below error.

```
XCUITest] Log file for xcodebuild test: /Users/msubramaniam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Logs/Test/D3F3B94A-A324-4996-B60F-0732CEBFB00D/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2017-05-30_125049-1uf7KZ.log
[Xcode] 2017-05-30 12:50:49.364 xcodebuild[87735:236610] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/msubramaniam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb4306026c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
[Xcode] 2017-05-30 12:50:49.364 xcodebuild[87735:236610] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED **
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1496128849419 (12:50:49 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
[XCUITest] Quitting and uninstalling WebDriverAgent, then retrying
[XCUITest] Shutting down sub-processes
[XCUITest] Shutting down iproxy process (pid 87701)
[XCUITest] iproxy exited with code 'null'
[XCUITest] Removing WDA application from device
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1496128859998 (12:50:59 GMT+0530 (IST))
```

As per the above log, I have navigated to the below location,

```
/Users/msubramaniam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

I found that there are two WebDriverAgents

```
WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy
WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs
```

It is calling the second WebDriverAgent and it does not have the "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app".

First WebDriverAgent has "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app".

So how to call the first WebDriverAgent.

I have also tried to remove the WebDriverAgent by using the below command.

```
rm -rf /WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs
```

But it is not deleted.

Kindly provide the solution for this to resolve.

Comment: I have removed that WebDriverAgent in Terminal, So it got removed in iphone.

Comment: is your app properly signed ?

Comment: can you add these two capabilities and then try to launch inspector:"agentPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj",
  "bootstrapPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent"

Comment: WebDriverAgentRunner build gets fialed in xcode due to "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgentLib/Routing/FBWebServer.m:12:9: 'RoutingHTTPServer/RoutingConnection.h' file not found"

Comment: navigate to WebDriverAgent project and run ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh

Comment: and then run xcodebuild command

Comment: It throws command "bootstrap" does not exist.

Comment: lets continue in the chat you pinged yesterday http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145444/discussion-between-mohan-kumar-and-abhinav

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145507/discussion-between-mohan-kumar-and-abhinav).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was issue with carthage. Ran below commands and it got resolved :

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/carthage' 
brew install carthage 
brew link carthage
```

Comment: I have done building the webDriverAgent on iPhone by using the below command

Comment: "xcodebuild build test -project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id='********' -configuration Debug"

Comment: but when I try to launch appium, via appium-desktop application as well as by using Terminal,  WebDriverAgent build gets deleted.

Comment: So again I ran the xcode command, it throws the below error in terminal

Comment: XCTRunner[434:667171] The bundle “WebDriverAgentRunner” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.

Comment: Can you check for desired capabilites ? also can you paste it over here

Comment: "platformName": "iOS",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "udid": "*******",
  "deviceName": "Ananda's iPhone",
  "bundleId": "com.apple.mobilesafari",
  "platformVersion": "10.3.1",
  "xcodeOrgId": "9Q6VZT6URH",
  "xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer",
  "agentPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgen‌​t.xcodeproj",
  "bootstrapPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent",
  "browserName": "Safari"

Comment: can you try appium 1.5.3 GUI version once ? and check whether it is able to open appium inspector or not. Start appium server from command line and then click on appium inspector from appium gui. (magnifying glass icon) (specify all settings in ios settings on appium gui before clicking inspector icon)

Comment: If I start the Appium server on Terminal and run the program, WebDriverAgent gets deleted

Comment: Is it fine if have appium 1.6.5 on Terminal and Appium 1.5.3 for GUI

Comment: Yes it is fine to use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145537/discussion-between-mohan-kumar-and-abhinav).