# How to inspect & write xpath on iPhone real device

Tags: java, ios, iphone, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

I am using the following details.

```
Appium : 1.6.4
Ios : 10.3.1
Mac : 10.12.4
```

I need to inspect the elements in iPhone and frame the Xpath. For that I am using "ios-inspector.html".

[image]

I can't see the proper html attribute here. So kindly help me how to inspect an elements and frame the Xpath.

Comment: Try using appium-desktop. https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop

Comment: I have installed appium-desktop too. But I am facing the below logs.

Comment: Please see the logs in this URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255460/the-file-webdriveragentrunner-runner-app-couldn-t-be-opened-because-there-is-n

Comment: try adding these two capabilities and then launch using appium-desktop:"agentPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj",
  "bootstrapPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent"

Comment: Also make sure that the app is properly signed.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, I am trying to install WebDriverAgent in iPhone by using the command "xcodebuild build test -project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id= '<Connected Device UDID>' -configuration Debug"        but it gets failed now..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145444/discussion-between-mohan-kumar-and-abhinav).

Comment: Are you using XCUITEST driver?

Comment: Yeah..!! XCUITEST driver..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was issue with carthage. Ran below commands and it got resolved :

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/carthage' 
brew install carthage 
brew link carthage
```